# using the html code in the javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var a="sreedhar";
         <input type="text" value="abc">
     </script>
</body>
```

It gives the syntax error.
  can't we use "html tags" directly in "javascript".

Comment: You can't. Just put the input tag outside the <script>

Comment: My eyes! Aaaagh :) Just kidding. Between `<script>` and `</script>` the only thing allowed is the scripting language you are using. Could you provide a more accurate question? What do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use them directly in JavaScript.

However you may treat them as strings:

```
var str = '<input type="text" value="abc">';
```

or as DOM elements:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.value = 'abc';
```

And then append to the markup, e.g. `document.body.appendChild(input);`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a well formated hmtl with javascript looks like this.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              var a="sreedhar";
        </script>
</HEAD>    
<BODY>
        <input type="text" value="abc">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate some html with javascript then assign it as a string to some variable.

For example you have a div having `id='abc'` and you want to generate a textbox in this div then you need to do like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var textbox = '<input type="text" value="abc">';
   $('#abc').append(textbox);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a="sreedhar";
document.write('<input type="text" value="abc">');
</script>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     //put javascript function here

  </script> 
 </head>

 <body>
     <input type="text" value="abc">
 </body>
</html>
```

You can use html element inside the javascript using element id.